# Question on Razor syntax

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

The stylesheet for my website can vary for every user. So the name of the css file is read from the database. I set the css name in ViewBag.StyleSheet and set it in my Razor file like this:

```
@section Scripts {
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/@ViewBag.StyleSheet.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}
```

But this is not working. Please help.

Comment: You forgot to mention how it's not working...

Comment: The ol' "not working" error, eh? These are best debugged with a "more info needed" request.

Comment: It's pretty obvious in this case why it wasn't working though. SLaks caught it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Url.Content` is a normal C# function call that takes a normal string.

You need to concatenate that string, like this:

```
@Url.Content("~/Content/" + ViewBag.StyleSheet + ".css")
```

Comment: thanks - I was trying @Url.Content("~/Content/" + @ViewBag.StyleSheet + ".css") and was not working

Comment: `@` is only used to render to the page; you should not use it in normal expressions.